# Spring Boot Ignite Set TTL for specific key

Tags: spring-boot, caching, ignite, ttl

I m prototyping something with Spring-Boot and Apache Ignite , Sping-Boot now provides Cache Implementation in terms of Cache manager , I want to create a session cache in Ignite using Spring boot with expire time of 30 min for cache . If keys set in this cache are not updated till 30 min then it should expire that key .I want to update TTL of particular keys  on every request .

```
Cache cache=  cacheManager.getCache("session-cache");
       cache.put("randome_key","value");
```

I want to do something like this

```
cache.setExpireTime(30)
```

I appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify an [expiry policy](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies) in the cache configuration:

```
CacheConfiguration cfg = new CacheConfiguration();
...
cfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(ModifiedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(Duration.ofMinutes(30));
```